# CodeIgniter V2 - Undefined property: Uploader::$mod_Photoalbums_model

Tags: php, codeigniter, properties, model, undefined

I have an controller for uploading

In that controller I get the following error

> Undefined property: Uploader::$mod_photoalbums_model
>   controllers/uploader.php
>   Line Number: 188

My uploader controller is

```
class Uploader extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->load->library('qquploadedfilexhr');
        $this->load->model('Uploader_model');
        $this->load->model('mod_Photoalbums_model');
//ETC
     }

//LINE 188
     public function insertIntoDatabase($id, $module, $filename, $thumbnail, $folder) {
         //MORE CODE 
         $result = $this->mod_Photoalbums_model->add_image($id, $module, $filename, $thumbnail, $folder);
         //MORE CODE
     }
}
```

The model

```
class mod_photoalbums_model extends MY_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    //ETC
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

I had "$this->load->library('qquploadedfilexhr');" in the  __construct
Placed that to the function and its working again.